# Is it bad practice to define/use "Preset" functions

Tags: programming-practices, language-agnostic

Lets say I have an extremely robust and versatile function:
`void DoAnything(action, target, context)`

In my program, 90% of the time I call this function, it's with the same parameters:
`DoAnything(eat, food, lunchtime);`

Is it bad form for me to define a function such as:
`void EatLunch(){  DoAnything(eat, food, lunchtime);  }`

And call that instead?

Comment: I would say that pretty much all functions do this in one way or another.

Comment: It would be bad practice *not* to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a *good* thing to do when you find the code is more readable and more maintainable when wrapped using the invariant arguments. I do it often.

Answer (score 6):

When you're writing a library, adding convenience wrappers is often a service to your users.

For example, suppose I've written a stream compression library in C.  My highly versatile entry point might be:

```
Stream *compress_stream(Stream *input, StreamOptions *opts);
```

However, many users will simply want a function like this:

```
void *compress(const void *data, size_t length, size_t *out_length);
```

`compress_stream` is more versatile: it can both consume input and produce output lazily, and the user can supply additional parameters (e.g. algorithm, quality, etc.)

However if a user simply has a blob of data they want to make smaller, my `compress_stream` function will be extremely cumbersome by itself.  The user will have to learn about my `Stream` object:

```
typedef struct Stream Stream;

struct Stream
{
    size_t (*read)(Stream *s, void *buffer, size_t len);
    void free(Stream *s);
};
```

Then they'll have to implement `compress` in their own terms:

```
typedef struct
{
    Stream stream;
    const char *data;
    size_t remaining;
} SimpleStream;

size_t SimpleStream_read(Stream *s, void *buffer, size_t len)
{
    SimpleStream *ss = container_of(s, Stream, stream);

    if (len > ss->remaining)
        len = ss->remaining;

    memcpy(buffer, ss->data, len);
    ss->data += len;
    ss->remaining -= len;
    return len;
}

void SimpleStream_free(Stream *s)
{
    free(container_of(s, Stream, stream));
}

Stream *SimpleStream_new(const void *data, size_t length)
{
    SimpleStream *ss = stream_new(sizeof(SimpleStream),
                                  SimpleStream_read,
                                  SimpleStream_free);
    if (ss == NULL)
        return NULL;

    ss->data = data;
    ss->remaining = length;
    return &ss->stream;
}

void *consume(Stream *s, size_t *out_length)
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t buffer_length = 0;
    size_t buffer_alloc = 16;

    buffer = malloc(buffer_alloc + 1);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return NULL;

    for (;;) {
        size_t readlen;

        readlen = s->read(s, buffer + buffer_length, buffer_alloc - buffer_length);
        if (readlen == 0)
            break;

        buffer_length += readlen;
        assert(buffer_length <= buffer_alloc);
        if (buffer_alloc - buffer_length < 16) {
            char *tmp;

            buffer_alloc *= 2;
            tmp = realloc(buffer, buffer_alloc + 1);
            if (tmp == NULL) {
                free(buffer);
                return NULL;
            }
            buffer = tmp;
        }
    }

    buffer[buffer_length] = 0;
    *out_length = buffer_length;
    return buffer;
}

void *compress(const void *data, size_t length, size_t *out_length)
{
    Stream *input;
    Stream *output;
    void *ret;

    input = SimpleStream_new(data, length);
    output = compress_stream(input, NULL);
    input->free(input);
    ret = consume(output, out_length);
    output->free(output);
    return ret;
}
```

This may be a contrived example, but I've seen libraries neglect to include simple wrappers on multiple occasions.  For users to implement those wrappers in their code, they will have to learn more about your library than they really wanted to.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, it's good form to do this. By defining what it means to `EatLunch()` in one place you reduce code repetition. Also, if ever you need to change what it means to `EatLunch()` then you only have to do so in one place.